# Netbeans unable to push to remote github repo

Tags: java, github, netbeans, version-control

This started just today, in the past I have been able to upload to repos without issue.

When I tried to add a new project to a new repo, I was given an error "cannot connect to the repmote repository at  in the gui window.

At first I suspected a connection problem so i tried to push another, existing project, using that project's default settings, and was given the dialog box error:
 Git command returned with the following error:
 : cannot open git-receive-pack

NetBeans IDE [image: when using remote>push command]8.0.2[image: when using remote>push to upstream command, with default settings for this repo]

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I have system proxy settings checked, I'm using my university ethernet connection, which ive used in the past without issue. I also tried with no proxy and encountered the same issue. "Test Connection" button gives me a green checkmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have the option to switch to SSH as a workaround.

But first, check if this is related to Netbeans, and upgrade from 8.0.2 to 8.2.
Make sure also to use the [latest Git](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html).

This could be related to the [recent "Weak cryptographic standards removal notice"](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/)

Comment: updating to 8.2 fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. It is not related with Netbeans ide. I was using my webaccount password whereas github requires an access token, that you can generate from your webaccount.

1. Generate access token (see: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token);
2. Use it as password in the password field in netbeans.